# Does zc.buildout offer a lot more than pip when dealing with packages/eggs

Tags: python, django, pip, buildout, egg

We're all development team working on a Django site. Recently we've begun using `zc.buildout` inside a `virtualenv`. I can see how `virtualenv` helps you by making a sandboxed environment. After creating a sandbox, one can simply use `pip` to install the necessary packages/eggs. I've read that `pip` can load all the eggs from a requirements file. This has made me question the benefits and additional functionality of `zc.buildout`. `zc.buildout` downloads the eggs that you mention in the `buildout.cfg` file but as I wrote, you can already do that using `pip` and a requirements file. Does `zc.buildout` do something more that I'm missing? I can already do all my automation using `Fabric.`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Buildout does much more than pip; each part is a separate recipe which can run arbitrary python code to get your tasks accomplished. Coupled with dependencies between the parts and update detection, zc.buildout is more comparable to make than to pip.

For example, using the `zc.recipe.cmmi` recipe, you can download and compile arbitrary "configure; make; make install" packages. There are recipes to generate files from templates, or create symlinks, or install specific software packages and configure these with buildout-controlled settings all in one step.

Installing eggs according to dependencies is just one of the tricks that zc.buildout supports.

Comment: I would add that another advantage for a team is that your environment  setup instructions for the new dev you just hired become simpler if you put the bootstrap.py and buildout.cfg in the repository. 

  $ python bootstrap.py --distribute

get to work :)